# Set view's public attributes in XAML

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

I often like to decompose my XAML file into smaller parts without making my controls fully standalone views. So instead of

```
<VerticalStackLayout>
   <Grid>
       <Label Text="item1" />
       ...
   </Grid>

   <Grid>
       <Label Text="item2" />
       ...
   </Grid>
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

I usually have (my page)

```
<VerticalStackLayout>
   <myconrols:MyItemView />
   <myconrols:MyItemView />
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

and a separate MyItemView

```
<Grid>
    <Label Text="item1" x:Name="NameLabel" x:FieldModifier="Public" />
    ...
```

Now is the question: Is it possible to set `NameLabel.Text` value form the page XAML file directly? Without defining boilerplate bindable properties? Something like

```
<mycontrols:MyItemView NameLabel.Text="item1" />
<mycontrols:MyItemView NameLabel.Text="item2" />
```

If it's not possible then how would you name this feature? (I think about creating a feature issue because I think it would be super useful)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to set NameLabel.Text value form the page XAML file
> directly? Without defining boilerplate bindable properties?

If you often reuse a layout, customizing a `Contenview` is a great way to do it.
And since we can't directly reference the control inside the `Contenview` via `x:Name` property, so we need to add necessary `BindableProperty` to it.

Here is a customized `Contenview`, you can refer to the code of it.

**MyItemView.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MyItemView : ContentView
{
      public MyItemView()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
      }

    public String YourName
    {
        get
        {
            String value = (String)GetValue(YourNameProperty);
            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(YourNameProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty YourNameProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(YourName)
    , typeof(String)
    , typeof(MyItemView), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnYourNameChanged);

    static void OnYourNameChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------> " + newValue);
    }
}
```

**MyItemView.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1124.Views.MyItemView"
               x:Name="myItemView"
             >
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Grid>
            <Label  Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference myItemView}, Path=YourName}" />
        </Grid>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

And here is the usage example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MauiApp1124.Views"
             x:Class="MauiApp1124.MainPage">

        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">
        <views:MyItemView YourName="welcome"></views:MyItemView>

        <views:MyItemView YourName="Hi"></views:MyItemView>

        </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

For more information, please check official document: [ContentView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/contentview?view=net-maui-8.0).